# C Programming while condition doesn't behave as expected or consistently

Tags: c

My son has C code for homework, and I am a perl/javascript person, and don't understand what's not working.  I understand this should be done better/different, however I think it should at least work!

```
float cashEuro, priceEuro, changeEuro;

cashEuro = 13.6;
priceEuro = 1.7;

changeEuro = cashEuro - priceEuro;
changeEuro = changeEuro * 100;

printf("\nchangeEuro before we start is %5.2f\n\n", changeEuro);

while (changeEuro >= 200) {
    changeEuro = changeEuro - 200;
    printf("I give you 2 Euro, and there is %5.2f left\n", changeEuro);
}

while (changeEuro >= 100) {
    changeEuro = changeEuro - 100;
    printf("I give you 1 Euro, and there is %5.2f left\n", changeEuro);
}

while (changeEuro >= 50) {
    changeEuro = changeEuro - 50;
    printf("I give you 50c, and there is %5.2f left\n", changeEuro);
}

while (changeEuro >= 20) {
    changeEuro = changeEuro - 20;
    printf("I give you 20c, and there is %5.2f left\n", changeEuro);
}

while (changeEuro >= 10) {
    changeEuro = changeEuro - 10;
    printf("I give you 10c, and there is %5.2f left\n", changeEuro);

}
```

The output is what I would expect:

```
changeEuro before we start is 1190.00

I give you 2 Euro, and there is 990.00 left
I give you 2 Euro, and there is 790.00 left
I give you 2 Euro, and there is 590.00 left
I give you 2 Euro, and there is 390.00 left
I give you 2 Euro, and there is 190.00 left
I give you 1 Euro, and there is 90.00 left
I give you 50c, and there is 40.00 left
I give you 20c, and there is 20.00 left
I give you 20c, and there is  0.00 left
```

But if I change the cashEuro value to 2.6 (expecting 50,20,20 in change), I get this

```
changeEuro before we start is 90.00

I give you 50c, and there is 40.00 left
I give you 20c, and there is 20.00 left
I give you 10c, and there is 10.00 left
```

I cannot fathom why the `while (changeEuro >= 20)` is not true when it has printed "there is 20.00 left" in the latter calculation, whilst it is true in the first one.  I am pulling my hair out!

Comment: `changeEuro = changeEuro * 100;` --> `changeEuro = round(changeEuro * 100.0);`

Comment: " I am pulling my hair out!" --> Print all `float` with `"%.9g"` like `printf("%.9g\n", changeEuro);` to see why.

Comment: `cashEuro = 2.6;printf("cashEuro is %.9f", cashEuro);`
results in `cashEuro is 2.599999905` ?!?!  is this specific to C, aware of float precision errors, but that seems really odd.

Comment: OK, I see the "is floating point math broken" link someone has used to mark as duplicate.  I was just reading Matt Parker on this, but never thought it would manifest in this way as I've used floats in perl for decades without this problem - somehow...

Comment: wcndave, `float` can exactly encode about 2^32 different values.  2.6 is **not**  one of them.  2.599999905.... is the closest alternative.  "seems really odd" --> Why is that?  Do you think a 32-bit `float` can exactly encode every value?  Recall a `float` is some integer times a power-of-2.  2.6 cannot be encoded that way.  (Curious, why use `"%.9f"` instead of the suggested `"%.9g"`?)

Comment: wcndave, "as I've used floats in pearl for decades without this problem" --> I suspect floats in Pearl are 64-bit.  In C, `float` is usually 32-bit and `double` 64-bit.  Same problem occurs with `double`, but after 15 significant decimals places rather than 6 with `float`.  IOWs a C `float` is likely less precise than Pearl.  (I am uncertain of Pearl details.)

Comment: wcndave, Why did you code `float cashEuro` and not `double cashEuro`?  Had you enable all compiler warnings `cashEuro = 13.6;` certainly would have given you a warning.  Save time.  Enable all warnings. (IMO, this is the most important take-way from this post.)

Comment: In general, do not use floating-point data types for currency calculation.

Comment: I think that as per comments, not using float for discrete values, plus 64 bit precision means I have not needed to deal with this before.  I would never use float for currency, but the teacher instructed son's class specifically to use float.  What can I do!